# Get the last 3 digits of the ip address and update current user bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am needing to get the last 3 digits of the users ip address of the computer the file is being ran on. After i do that i would like to update the current user, users name to dra123 (where 123 represents the ip address)

How can i do this? 
Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get last three digits of IPV4:

```
for /F "tokens=4 delims=.:" %%G in (
    'ping -4 %COMPUTERNAME%^|find "Reply from"'
) do set "IP=000%%G"
set "last3digits=%IP:~-3%"
```

Adds leading zeroes, e.g. gives `002` for IP=`192.168.1.2`

Sorry, I have no advice how to change current user name , but you could use output from next commands to learn yourself:

```
wmic USERACCOUNT where "name='%username%'" get * /format:Textvaluelist.xsl

wmic USERACCOUNT /?

wmic USERACCOUNT set /?
```

**Edit** Truly and in brief only: not trivial, not one-step procedure and a lot of consequences. You are about to change `username` (usually referenced as `%username%`) but there is a coherence in *literally* used `username`. For instance (absolutely *not exhaustive* list):

```
for /F "tokens=*" %G in ('set^|find /I "%username%"') do @echo %G
for /F "tokens=*" %G in ('reg query "HKCU\Volatile Environment"^|find /I "%username%"') do @echo %G
for /F "tokens=*" %G in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"^|find /I "%username%"') do @echo %G
```

Not sure Windows do all changes to keep consistency (Windows XP didn't)

Comment: And updating the current username to `dra123`? Not that I care (and if you understand that, you would be moving in some very strange circles)

Comment: `wmic useraccount where name='%USERNAME%' rename %USERNAME%%last3digits%` when run as an Administrator will change the username.

Comment: @Magoo Probably I know the command(s), but I'd beware and avoid of using that... That's why _I have no advice_ :)

Comment: @Magoo why do you not recommend this?

Comment: @JosefZ why do you think this is a bad idea.

Comment: Recommend? I made no recommendations, positive or negative. My comment was simply that the response generated the last-3-digits, but didn't set "current user" to `DRA123`. Quite what you mean by that - set `username` for the current `cmd` session, or some other purpose, I've no idea (you could possibly auto-login with a username of `dra123` on each machine and not need this batch for instance.) As for not caring - any aficionado of Empire of the Petal Throne would understand that immediately. Others - it would take far too long to explain...